# Excel macro which converts shift hours into length of the shift

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make macro (or function) in excel for my work schedule. I want that when someone enters shift hours, eg. 7-14, it will write 7 in the cell below. It should be flexible because I have many different shift hours like 8-14, 9-14, 11-20, 14-21, etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you familiar with the `LEFT`, `MID` and `FIND` functions?

Comment: This shouldn't need VBA. A formula would be easier. Easier still if the start & end times are entered in different cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no split function in Excel, so you need to use the `find` and `mid` functions to capture the text before and after a split character.

If the text in A1 is 7-15, you can use this formula in A2

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,10)) - NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))
```

Value shown

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the duration of the shift the formula below would provide that. The shift limits are in cell A1. Add $-signs to the reference as required for your copying plans.

```
=ABS(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)))-INT(NUMBERVALUE(A1,"-"))
```

However, by entering shifts like "7-14" you have the worst of all worlds because there is no end to the possible entry errors, reading and processing the data is difficult, and calculation of partial hours or shifts over midnight is impossible.

Splitting start and end times into separate columns reduces the above disadvantages significantly but I suspect that a simple numbering system will be better for your needs. Imagine a table somewhere in your workbook where you list the shifts with start and end times, giving each shift a number, like

```
1    7:00    14:00
2    8:00    14:00
3   11:00    20:00
etc.
```

Then, in your time sheet you just enter the shift number and do your calculations using VLOOKUP. This system would combine the least likelihood of entry mistakes with the greatest flexibility in calculating times because all times are set centrally in one table.